# Removing duplicate elements using distinct-values and xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to solve a problem where I want to remove duplicate values from a sequence of elements.

I've played around with this for a while now, and the code below sort of looks like something I thought would work, but I am getting an error:

XPTY0020: Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the tree containing the context item: the context item is not a node

The XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/tobject/tobject.subject/@tobject.subject.refnum)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tobject tobject.type="Utenriks">
    <tobject.property tobject.property.type="Nyheter"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04005000" tobject.subject.matter="olje og energi"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11000000" tobject.subject.type="politikk"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11000000" tobject.subject.type="politikk"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11003000" tobject.subject.matter="valg"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="KRE" tobject.subject.refnum="02000000" tobject.subject.type="kriminalitet og rettsvesen"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="FRI" tobject.subject.refnum="10000000" tobject.subject.type="fritid"/>
</tobject>
```

The wanted outcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tobject tobject.type="Utenriks">
    <tobject.property tobject.property.type="Nyheter"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04005000" tobject.subject.matter="olje og energi"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11000000" tobject.subject.type="politikk"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11003000" tobject.subject.matter="valg"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="KRE" tobject.subject.refnum="02000000" tobject.subject.type="kriminalitet og rettsvesen"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="FRI" tobject.subject.refnum="10000000" tobject.subject.type="fritid"/>
</tobject>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the code below sort of looks like something I thought would work, but
>   I am getting an error:
>
> XPTY0020: Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the tree
>   containing the context item: the context item is not a node

This error cannot be reproduced running your code - see: http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQfa

However, the result of `distinct-values()` is a sequence of *values*, not *nodes*. The result that you expect - removing duplicate *elements* -  is much easier to achieve using grouping:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/tobject">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | tobject.property"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="tobject.subject" group-by="@tobject.subject.refnum">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I. An even shorter solution** **that is pure XSLT 1.0** and doesn't need unnecessary element names.

Plus, it is not less efficient than an XSLT 2.0 solution that uses `<xsl:for-each-group>` -- because **here we use the Muenchian method for grouping:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kOS" match="tobject.subject" use="@tobject.subject.refnum"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
  "tobject.subject[generate-id() != generate-id(key('kOS', @tobject.subject.refnum)[1])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<tobject tobject.type="Utenriks">
    <tobject.property tobject.property.type="Nyheter"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04005000" tobject.subject.matter="olje og energi"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11000000" tobject.subject.type="politikk"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11000000" tobject.subject.type="politikk"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11003000" tobject.subject.matter="valg"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="KRE" tobject.subject.refnum="02000000" tobject.subject.type="kriminalitet og rettsvesen"/>
    <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="FRI" tobject.subject.refnum="10000000" tobject.subject.type="fritid"/>
</tobject>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<tobject tobject.type="Utenriks">
   <tobject.property tobject.property.type="Nyheter"/>
   <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000" tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
   <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04005000" tobject.subject.matter="olje og energi"/>
   <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11000000" tobject.subject.type="politikk"/>
   <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11003000" tobject.subject.matter="valg"/>
   <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="KRE" tobject.subject.refnum="02000000" tobject.subject.type="kriminalitet og rettsvesen"/>
   <tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="FRI" tobject.subject.refnum="10000000" tobject.subject.type="fritid"/>
</tobject>
```

---

**II. A One-liner XPath 2.0 expression that selects the wanted unique (one from each group elements**

```
$vElems[index-of($vElems/@tobject.subject.refnum, @tobject.subject.refnum)[1]]
```

Here $vElems must be defined as:

```
/*/tobject.subject
```

**When this XPath 2.0 expression is evaluated on the provided XML document, the wanted sequence of elements is selected**:

```
<tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04000000"
             tobject.subject.type="økonomi og næringsliv"/>
<tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="OKO" tobject.subject.refnum="04005000"
             tobject.subject.matter="olje og energi"/>
<tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11000000"
             tobject.subject.type="politikk"/>
<tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="POL" tobject.subject.refnum="11003000"
             tobject.subject.matter="valg"/>
<tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="KRE" tobject.subject.refnum="02000000"
             tobject.subject.type="kriminalitet og rettsvesen"/>
<tobject.subject tobject.subject.code="FRI" tobject.subject.refnum="10000000"
             tobject.subject.type="fritid"/>
```